munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer Aborted (core dumped)
Running this to read numbers from argv[1], which is a file results in "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer Aborted (core dumped)"
This error only occurs if the first line contains a number that is two or more digits, for instance, the following doesn't crash:
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19

but this crashes
10 
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20

//-------------------------- READ------------------------------//
//-------------------------- READ------------------------------//
if (command == "Read"){
    cout << command << endl;
    ifstream inputFile(argv[1]);

    if (!inputFile){
        cout << "CANNOT READ" << endl;
        continue;
    }
    else{
        string line; 
        getline(inputFile, line);
        number_of_elements = stoi(line);
        
        int count = 1;
        vector<int> key_values(number_of_elements);                    
        pHeap= new HEAP;
        pHeap->size = 0;
        pHeap->capacity = number_of_elements;  
        
        while(getline(inputFile, line)){
            if(count == number_of_elements + 1){
                break;
            }
            else if(line.length() == 0){
                if(count != number_of_elements)
                    continue;
                else
                    break;
            }
            else if(line.length() > 0){
                key_values[count] = stod(line);
                ++count; 
            }
        V = new ELEMENT*[number_of_elements];

        for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_elements; i++){
            V[i] = new ELEMENT;
            V[i]->index = i;
            V[i]->key = key_values[i];
            V[i]->pos = 0;
        }
    }
}

Changing
V = new ELEMENT*(number_of_elements); into
V = new ELEMENT*(number_of_elements * sizeof(ELEMENET)); solves this issue but creates other problems so this, I think, is the simpler one to solve.

First edit your question, your code has commented out sections and is not formatted correctly. Which makes it hard to focus on the MRE (I really doubt all the file IO matters)

Please create a [mcve], empahsis on minimal.

Taking the questionable section of code out of the greater program, and putting it into an example code whose purpose is only to display the questionable behavior, is an important step of debugging. Quite often you will understand the problem while preparing the example, and if you don't, having a stand-alone program to reproduce it (instead of a snippet) is helpful to others (us). I call it machete debugging.

I will create a minimal reproducible example asap but I just realized my laptop is at 3% now.

Both with key_values and V, you loop over indexes 1..n, with n being the number of elements.
C++ (and basically every other programming language) counts indexes from 0..(n-1). vector<int> key_values(number_of_elements); will give you a vector of number_of_elements elements, indexed from 0 through number_of_elements - 1. Accessing key_values[number_of_elements] is an out-of-range access, and undefined behavior.
So count = 1 should be count = 0, and if(count == number_of_elements + 1) should be if(count == number_of_elements).
And for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_elements; i++) should be for (int i = 0; i < number_of_elements; ++i).

the i <= number_of_elements  condition should take care of that.

@Mea12 No. The last loop will be with i = number_of_elements (less than or equal), and indices of V only run from 0 to number_of_elements - 1.

@Mea12 Unrelated to the Q, but in idiomatic C++, you should not allocate objects on the heap with new and assign them to "owning" pointers. You should never do that outside of a constructor (with the corresponding delete in the destructor). If you have to create heap objects anywhere else (and usually within constructors as well), you should be using smart pointers. That helps a lot with avoiding memory leaks.

oh my… you’re right then should the length of ‘’’V’’’ be ‘’’number_of_elements + 1’’’?

@Mea12 You might also want to look into range for. Right now you're using mostly C constructs instead of C++ ones. This leads to many very unnecessary errors, and usually not-so-nice code as well.

@Mea12 No. The size of V[number_of_elements] is number_of_elements. Let's say you declare V[3]. (Not that you should, because you should be using vector, but anyway.) You then have 3 elements: V[0], V[1], and V[2].

I understand, but because I’m building an implementation of a max heap I need the first index to be 1 so that right and left indices are easier to get but I get I guess I can get around that too

@Mea12 Use at instead of [] (e.g.V.at(i) instead of V[i]). If you have an index out of bounds then at gives you a predictable std::out_of_range exception immediately instead of an unpredictable crash later on.

@john True technically, but terrible advise for the general case. Using .at() everywhere is much slower than direct indexed access, and really unnecessary other than during debugging. The idiomatic solution here would be utilizing <algorithm>, or at the very least range-for, eliminating the use of indices altogether.

@Mea12 Building custom data containers is another thing from C times that makes C++ beginners struggle. What was really necessary in C (building container functionality from the bare minimums C provided) is really really unnecessary in C++, which comes with a rich selection of data containers in its standard library so you don't have to write them. At the same time, a good C++ data container is a much more involved thing if you want it to play properly with the beauty that is <algorithm>. Perhaps re-think your practice project.
